# conversion to float in R

Tags: r

I have a set of Latitudes stored in VARCHAR format in mysql database-

```
"[26.455359183496455,26.44229519242908,26.437069181137474,26.45489812668682]"
```

I have imported them in R and I want to work with them by converting them as float. I know that `as.numeric()` is used for conversion but how to apply it in my case.
someone please guide me.

Comment: Do you only have the one string? Or do you have a data frame with a column of these strings? Are there always 4 latitudes in a string or does it vary by row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in three steps.

1. remove the brackets (via `gsub()`,
2. split on commas (via `strsplit()`,
3. convert to numeric (via `as.numeric()`). For example

In code this looks like

```
input <- "[26.455359183496455,26.44229519242908,26.437069181137474,26.45489812668682]"
as.numeric(strsplit(gsub("(^\\[|\\]$)", "", input), ",")[[1]])
```

Comment: why the type of `as.numeric(strsplit(gsub("(^\\[|\\]$)", "", input), ",")[[1]])` is `double` rather than `list`?

Comment: @MrFlick does this convert it to `float` or `integer`?

Comment: @Dij The numeric type in R generally switched between integer and float depending on which is more appropriate for the data. If there are decimals, it will use float.

Comment: @MrFlick do you know if there is a way to force it to produce float?

Comment: @Dij you can use `as.double()`. R uses double precision floating point numbers.

Comment: as.numeric() is equivalent to as.double(). These give double precision floats. If you just want to coerce the number to a (single) float, then as.single() can be used.